# Memory Leak when using Fire Base Storage Download

Tags: swift, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage, uicollectionviewcell, collectionview

I have a program that has two tabs, each run with its own view controller. The second tab is a basic screen that displays a button, while the first tab is a `UICollectionView` that displays a few `UICollectionViewCell`s that have an image and a label.

I seem to have a very large memory leak when switching from the `UICollectionView` tab to the other tab. I've determined that both viewcontrollers are properly hitting `deinit`, and my `UICollectionViewCell`s are also deinitilizing, so I think the issue lies in how I am pulling in my data. It seems to be that the firebase call and the image it returns is never deallocated.

Can someone help figure out what I am doing wrong?

The `UICollectionViewCell` is defined as follows

```
class InteractionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var Photo: UIImageView!
    var Id:String?
    @IBOutlet weak var personLabel: UILabel!
    func configure(_ person:Person) {
        self.Id = person:Person.id
        FirebaseInstance.GetPersonProfilePicture(person.id) { image in
            self.Photo.image = image
        }
    }
}
```

And `GetPersonProfilePicture` is:

```
class FirebaseInstance {
    static private let StorageInst:StorageReference = Storage.storage().reference()
    static var StorageRef:StorageReference = StorageInst
    static private let ImageMaxSize = Int64(1 * 1024 * 1024)

    static func GetPersonProfilePicture(_ userUID:String, completion: @escaping (UIImage) -> Void) {
        StorageRef.child("\(userUID)").getData(maxSize: ImageMaxSize) { data, error in
            if let error = error {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
                return
            } else {
                let downloadedImage = UIImage(data: data!)
                completion(downloadedImage!)
            }
        }
    }
```

EDIT: If I remove the line where I save the profile picture, the memory leak goes away, which is more proof that the memory leak seems to be in how I download the images.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah! I figured it out. It actually had nothing to do with how I was downloading the images at all.

My issue was that I was retrieving the cells by calling `.addSnapshotListener` on a `collection` in the `Cloud Firestore`. However, I wasn't ever removing the listener, which meant that my `UICollectionView` was never getting deinitialized, which was causing the huge memory leak.

By calling `mySnapshotListener.remove()` inside `viewWillDisapper` of the first controller, I was able to get rid of the memory leak.